# Why this Wordpress custom Search not working anymore?

Tags: php, wordpress, search

I'm confused and in need of some help with the follow custom Search I've used in my Wordpress webiste. It was working perfectly when in Local environment (Local by Flywheel). But when it went online for real, stopped working.

When I use any "post_type" in the $search_query like:

$search_query = array( 'post_type' => 'news' );

Then, works fine.

But my intention is use this Search like general Search of all the website. Was working great in my Local. Any help would be appreciate.

```
     <?php

        global $query_string;
        $query_args = explode("&", $query_string);
        $search_query = array();

        foreach($query_args as $key => $string) {
          $query_split = explode("=", $string);
          $search_query[$query_split[0]] = urldecode($query_split[1]); }

        $wp_query = new WP_Query($search_query);

        if ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : 

        global $wp_query;
        $total_results = $wp_query->found_posts;

     ?>    

     <?php while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>

     <div class="col-md-8 resuls">
            <h1>Search result(s): <?php echo $total_results ; ?></b> </h1>

            <?php while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>                     
                <h4><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h4>
                <h6><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_permalink(); ?></a></h6>
                <?php the_content(); ?>
                <hr>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
            </div>
        <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

And the Searchform code is exactly the same that worked in Local:

```
        <form class="input-group search" method="get" action="<?php echo home_url(); ?>" role="search">
            <input type="search" class="form-control search-field" placeholder="<?php echo esc_attr_x( 'Buscar / Search', 'placeholder' ) ?>" value="<?php echo get_search_query() ?>" name="s" />
            <span class="input-group-btn">
              <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" role="button" style="margin-left:0;"><i class="icon-search"></i></button>
            </span>
        </form>
```